# Spread with duplicate identifiers (using tidyverse and %>%)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse, dcast

## My data looks like this:

[image]

## I am trying to make it look like this:

[image]

I would like to do this in tidyverse using %>%-chaining.

```
df <- 
structure(list(id = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), start_end = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("end", "start"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("1979-01-03", 
    "1979-06-21", "1979-07-18", "1989-09-12", "1991-01-04", "1994-05-01", 
    "1996-11-04", "2005-02-01", "2009-09-17", "2010-10-01", "2012-10-06"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "start_end", "date"
), row.names = c(3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

## What I have tried:

```
data.table::dcast( df, formula = id ~ start_end, value.var = "date", drop = FALSE )  # does not work because it summarises the data

tidyr::spread( df, start_end, date )  # does not work because of duplicate values


df$id2 <- 1:nrow(df)
tidyr::spread( df, start_end, date ) # does not work because the dataset now has too many rows.
```

These questions do not answer my question:

[Using spread with duplicate identifiers for rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053451/using-spread-with-duplicate-identifiers-for-rows)  (because they summarise)

[R: spread function on data frame with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209388/r-spread-function-on-data-frame-with-duplicates)  (because they paste the values together)

[Reshaping data in R with "login" "logout" times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932291/reshaping-data-in-r-with-login-logout-times) (because not specifically asking for/answered using tidyverse and chaining)

Comment: `as.data.table(df)[, .id := sequence(.N), .(id, start_end)][, dcast(.SD, .id + id ~ start_end, value.var = "date")]`?

Comment: Using `reshape2` and `dplyr`: `df %>% group_by(id, start_end) %>% arrange(date) %>% mutate(sequence=1:n()) %>% dcast(id + sequence ~ start_end, value="date")`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`.  After grouping by 'start_end', 'id', create a sequence column 'ind' , then `spread` from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   group_by(start_end, id) %>%
   mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
   spread(start_end, date) %>% 
   select(start, end)
#     id      start        end
#* <int>     <fctr>     <fctr>
#1     2 1994-05-01 1996-11-04
#2     4 1979-07-18         NA
#3     5 2005-02-01 2009-09-17
#4     5 2010-10-01 2012-10-06
```

---

Or using `tidyr_1.0.0`

```
chop(df, date) %>%
     spread(start_end, date) %>%
     unnest(c(start, end))
```