# Turning variable values into column names; "duplicate identifiers for rows" in tidyr::spread

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

I am working with a messy voter file. Consider the following `tibble`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat <- tibble(
  id = factor(c("A","B","C","D","E")),
  demographic_info1 = round(rnorm(5),2),
  demographic_info2 = round(rnorm(5),2),
  election_1 = c(NA,"GN2016","GN2016","SE2016","GN2008"),
  election_2 = c(NA,"MT2014","GN2012","GN2016","GN2004"),
  election_3 = c(NA,NA,NA,"MT2014","GN2000"),
  election_4 = c(NA,NA,NA,"GN2012",NA),
  election_5 = c(NA,NA,NA,"MT2010",NA),
)
```

Which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 8
      id demographic_info1 demographic_info2 election_1 election_2 election_3 election_4 election_5
  <fctr>             <dbl>             <dbl>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
1      A             -1.50              0.81       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2      B             -1.84             -0.64     GN2016     MT2014       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
3      C              1.66             -0.10     GN2016     GN2012       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
4      D              0.91             -0.08     SE2016     GN2016     MT2014     GN2012     MT2010
5      E              0.04             -1.15     GN2008     GN2004     GN2000       <NA>       <NA>
```

- Each `id` is a unique identifier for a voter.
- The two `demographic_info` columns are filler, just to demonstrate that I want to *retain* these values when I do my reshaping of the data.

The columns `election_1` to `election_5` are what I am interested in. The data are structured such that the file includes the most recent 5 elections someone has participated in. `election_1` is the most recent, `election_5` is the least recent.

Note that person `A` has never turned out to vote, while person `D` always does. What I would like to do is turn these columns into a number of variables: `SE2016`, `GN2016`, `MT2014`, `GN2012`, etc.; that is, all of the values in `election_1` to `election_5`. I would like each of these to be variables that are either `TRUE` or `FALSE` for whether or not that person showed up to the polls. I have tried this code:

```
dat %>% # take data
  gather(election, race, election_1:election_5) %>% # gather by election
  mutate(temp=TRUE) %>% # make new variable that is all TRUE
  select(-election) %>% # drop election variable
  spread(race, temp, fill=FALSE) # spread by this all TRUE variable, fill all NAs as FALSE
```

However, `spread` throws the error:

```
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 6, 11, 16, 21), (12, 17, 22), (13, 18, 23), (20, 25)
```

This is because there are multiple entries for each of the values of the `race` variable. I've tried to `group_by(id)` before doing the `spread`, but the same error is thrown.

I would like the resulting `tibble` to look like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 11
      id demographic_info1 demographic_info2 SE2016 GN2016 MT2014 GN2012 MT2010 GN2008 GN2004 GN2000
  <fctr>             <dbl>             <dbl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
1      A             -0.91             -0.56  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
2      B              1.24             -1.78  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
3      C              0.61              0.11  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
4      D              2.43             -0.53   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
5      E             -1.40             -1.23  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
```

Comment: You need to create a sequence column by group before doing the `spread`

Comment: @akrun does the `id` variable not count as a sequence column? Not sure I follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tidyr provides some syntax for dealing with this problem.

```
# set up
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat <- tibble(
  id = factor(c("A","B","C","D","E")),
  demographic_info1 = round(rnorm(5),2),
  demographic_info2 = round(rnorm(5),2),
  election_1 = c(NA,"GN2016","GN2016","SE2016","GN2008"),
  election_2 = c(NA,"MT2014","GN2012","GN2016","GN2004"),
  election_3 = c(NA,NA,NA,"MT2014","GN2000"),
  election_4 = c(NA,NA,NA,"GN2012",NA),
  election_5 = c(NA,NA,NA,"MT2010",NA)
)
```

What we eventually want is a `TRUE` or `FALSE` for every voter (5) x election (8) pairing. When we gather the data into a long format, we only see the voter x election combinations *that exist* in the data-set.

```
d_votes <- dat %>%
  gather("variable", "election", election_1:election_5) %>%
  select(-variable) %>%
  mutate(voted = TRUE)
d_votes
#> # A tibble: 25 x 5
#>        id demographic_info1 demographic_info2 election voted
#>    <fctr>             <dbl>             <dbl>    <chr> <lgl>
#>  1      A              0.76             -0.23     <NA>  TRUE
#>  2      B             -0.80              0.08   GN2016  TRUE
#>  3      C             -0.33              1.60   GN2016  TRUE
#>  4      D             -0.50             -1.27   SE2016  TRUE
#>  5      E             -1.03              0.59   GN2008  TRUE
#>  6      A              0.76             -0.23     <NA>  TRUE
#>  7      B             -0.80              0.08   MT2014  TRUE
#>  8      C             -0.33              1.60   GN2012  TRUE
#>  9      D             -0.50             -1.27   GN2016  TRUE
#> 10      E             -1.03              0.59   GN2004  TRUE
#> # ... with 15 more rows

count(d_votes, election)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   election     n
#>      <chr> <int>
#> 1   GN2000     1
#> 2   GN2004     1
#> 3   GN2008     1
#> 4   GN2012     2
#> 5   GN2016     3
#> 6   MT2010     1
#> 7   MT2014     2
#> 8   SE2016     1
#> 9     <NA>    13
```

We need to generate every combination of voter and election. tidyr's `expand()` function creates all combinations of variables from different columns/vectors of data. (It works like the base function `expand.grid()`, so the name `expand()` is evocative).

```
d_possible_votes <- d_votes %>%
  expand(nesting(id, demographic_info1, demographic_info2),
         election)
d_possible_votes
#> # A tibble: 40 x 4
#>        id demographic_info1 demographic_info2 election
#>    <fctr>             <dbl>             <dbl>    <chr>
#>  1      A              0.76             -0.23   GN2000
#>  2      A              0.76             -0.23   GN2004
#>  3      A              0.76             -0.23   GN2008
#>  4      A              0.76             -0.23   GN2012
#>  5      A              0.76             -0.23   GN2016
#>  6      A              0.76             -0.23   MT2010
#>  7      A              0.76             -0.23   MT2014
#>  8      A              0.76             -0.23   SE2016
#>  9      B             -0.80              0.08   GN2000
#> 10      B             -0.80              0.08   GN2004
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

Note that we now have 8 elections x 5 ids = 40 rows.

We used the `nesting()` function to treat each (`id`, `demographic_info1`, `demographic_info2`) set/row as a single unit; demographics are *nested* within ids. Expanding provided all 40 combinations of (`id`, `demographic_info1`, `demographic_info2`) x `election`.

If we join the observed votes onto the possible votes, the `voted` column is populated with `TRUE` or `NA` values. tidyr's `replace_na()` function can correct those `NA` values.

```
d_possible_votes <- d_possible_votes %>%
  left_join(d_votes) %>%
  replace_na(list(voted = FALSE))
#> Joining, by = c("id", "demographic_info1", "demographic_info2", "election")
d_possible_votes
#> # A tibble: 40 x 5
#>        id demographic_info1 demographic_info2 election voted
#>    <fctr>             <dbl>             <dbl>    <chr> <lgl>
#>  1      A              0.76             -0.23   GN2000 FALSE
#>  2      A              0.76             -0.23   GN2004 FALSE
#>  3      A              0.76             -0.23   GN2008 FALSE
#>  4      A              0.76             -0.23   GN2012 FALSE
#>  5      A              0.76             -0.23   GN2016 FALSE
#>  6      A              0.76             -0.23   MT2010 FALSE
#>  7      A              0.76             -0.23   MT2014 FALSE
#>  8      A              0.76             -0.23   SE2016 FALSE
#>  9      B             -0.80              0.08   GN2000 FALSE
#> 10      B             -0.80              0.08   GN2004 FALSE
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

Now, we can spread out the elections and achieve the desired dataframe.

```
spread(d_possible_votes, election, voted)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 11
#>       id demographic_info1 demographic_info2 GN2000 GN2004 GN2008 GN2012 GN2016 MT2010 MT2014 SE2016
#> * <fctr>             <dbl>             <dbl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
#> 1      A              0.76             -0.23  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#> 2      B             -0.80              0.08  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
#> 3      C             -0.33              1.60  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#> 4      D             -0.50             -1.27  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#> 5      E             -1.03              0.59   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

This pattern of generating combinations of identifiers, joining actual data, and correcting missing values is very common—so much so that tidyr includes a function `complete()` to do all three at once.

```
d_votes %>%
  complete(nesting(id, demographic_info1, demographic_info2),
           election, fill = list(voted = FALSE)) %>%
  spread(election, voted)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 11
#>       id demographic_info1 demographic_info2 GN2000 GN2004 GN2008 GN2012 GN2016 MT2010 MT2014 SE2016
#> * <fctr>             <dbl>             <dbl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
#> 1      A              0.76             -0.23  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#> 2      B             -0.80              0.08  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
#> 3      C             -0.33              1.60  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#> 4      D             -0.50             -1.27  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#> 5      E             -1.03              0.59   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation on how `complete` works. I wasn't aware of that function! What are your thoughts on my solution, in comparison? My code feels less elegant, but `microbenchmark` says it runs quicker (about 6 milliseconds quicker, which could mean a lot when I run it on the 1GB file)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `group_by` on 'id' to create a sequence variable as the 'id' is duplicated and later remove it after the `spread`

```
dat %>%
   gather(election, race, election_1:election_5) %>%
   mutate(temp=TRUE)%>% group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(i1 = row_number()) %>% 
   select(-election) %>%
   spread(race, temp, fill=FALSE) %>%
   select(-i1)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Just to make sure I understand *why* this is working: `i1` provides a unique identifier within each group...?

Comment: @MarkWhite Yes, because there are 5 rows each for each 'id' i.e. `dat %>% gather(election, race, election_1:election_5) %>% mutate(temp=TRUE)%>% count(id) %>% .$n#
[1] 5 5 5 5 5`  So the 'i1' creates the sequence of 1, 2, ,3, ..5 for each 'id' and it can help in spread

Comment: On second glance, using this on my actual dataset: The code above creates five rows for every `id`; one row for every `election_*` field.

Comment: I've seen your other responses, too, like this one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43259735/7903456). It seems like it should work for my purposes, but for some reason I get a new row for every `election_*` field.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there were duplicate entries for `NA` values. I solved the problem of the duplicated identifiers *and* the multiple rows problem from akrun's answer by taking only `unique` rows, then grouping by `id`:

```
dat %>%
  gather(election, race, election_1:election_5) %>%
  mutate(temp=TRUE) %>%
  select(-election) %>%
  unique() %>% # GET RID OF DUPLICATE NA ENTRIES
  group_by(id) %>% 
  spread(race, temp, fill=FALSE) %>%
  select(-`<NA>`)
```

---

```
# A tibble: 5 x 11
# Groups:   id [5]
      id demographic_info1 demographic_info2 GN2000 GN2004 GN2008 GN2012 GN2016 MT2010 MT2014 SE2016
* <fctr>             <dbl>             <dbl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
1      A             -1.19             -0.94  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
2      B              1.41             -0.62  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
3      C             -0.21              1.62  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
4      D              1.51              0.09  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
5      E              0.65             -2.09   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```