# Spread rows into columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have two columns: one that contains the name of the variables and one that contains their respective values. It is only two variables, with three observations each, like in the example that follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  var = rep(letters[1:2],3),
  vals = c(1:6)
) %>% 
  arrange(var)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  var    vals
  <chr> <int>
1 a         1
2 a         3
3 a         5
4 b         2
5 b         4
6 b         6
```

The problem is that I need to turn `a` and `b` into columns, like in this **expected output**:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     3     4
3     5     6
```

I have tried doing this with `tidyr::spread` with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting the duplicate identifiers error?  You need uniquely identified rows. See comments and answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48383605/spread-with-duplicate-identifiers-for-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a sequence column after grouping by 'var'.  It will also make sure that for groups that are not having the same number of elements, the remaining values can be filled by a choice value (by default, it is `NA`)

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(var, vals) %>% 
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      a     b
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     2
#2     3     4
#3     5     6
```

#### data

```
tbl <- tibble(
  var = rep(letters[1:2],3),
  vals = c(1:6)
   ) %>% 
     arrange(var)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `unstack`

```
tbl <- tibble(
  var = rep(letters[1:2],3),
  vals = c(1:6)
) %>% 
  arrange(var)

unstack(tbl, vals ~ var)
#  a b
#1 1 2
#2 3 4
#3 5 6
```